# Which peninsula sink vent strategy is best for this situation?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, kitchen-sink

I am doing a remodel where I am removing a wall behind my sink to create a peninsula. This wall has my drain waste vent. So as far as code I do know that I cannot go less than 45 degrees (horizontal) until I am at least 6" above the sink flood plane. I should be able to make that work as I will be keeping a partial wall 16" to the right of the current drain.

I definitely can do a 45 degree vent. Though I might have the vent 45 possibly below the current sanitary tee. Reason being if I lower the whole p-trap then I lose more space in my cabinet #4 Or I will need to do a 90 jog #5 from the p-trap to the sanitary tee. So for those plumbers out there which solution would be most code compliant or is there a vent diagram that shows me a better solution? Thanks!

---

Notes, Single drain sink with garbage disposal. Also because of remodel and not wanting to move the current waste line (in concrete with the water lines on either side of it) the waste line will be to the far right of the cabinet. Sort of like #2.

[image: Vent below Sanitary Tee]

Comment: #4 looks the most practical I don’t see a reason to reconfigure the under sink set up as long as the height of the wall stub is same. But if the wall is being removed where is the now 45 degree vent stack going to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the illustrations! I'd go with Option #4 where the sink connection and trap are done right. Trap parallel with wall and drain immediately elbowed. Trap is as low as needed and no forgotten odd in-wall setup while hanging a serving shelf type of situation.

[image: DrainedRightForOnce.jpg]

In the case of a Garbage Disposal (GD), you'd use the GD itself as the elbow. Or, like the picture, you'd send that to the back ASAP as well.

[image: DrainedRightForOnce2.jpg]

Now, if you want to go nuts, literally, and get away from cleanouts or slip joints. Then, you'd glue-in union fittings under the sink so the entire drain start is solid-state and drops out for snaking. The picture is for using the trap as your elbow, but displays the union wonderfulness.

[image: DrainedRightForOnce3.jpg]

Comment: thanks for the options. I think what you really opened my eyes to moving the p-trap itself. It doesn't have to be the first thing out of the disposal. That and I will see if I can do a union fitting so I don't need a cleanout. Much appreciated! I will post an update layout later and take a pic when I am completely done. I also update my post to clarify a couple of things.

Comment: You're very welcome. Yeah, the unions are surprisingly a new thing to inspectors (outside of a gas line or swimming pool system), but the handful that had an initial pull-back came around...since you don't have a legal or legal-enough cleanout that catches debris and becomes its own job security. I hope it works out and look forward to the end result.